# Is 'dispatch_async' deprecated in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift4, grand-central-dispatch, deprecated, dispatch-async

I'm following  a tutorial on the internet for creating an app, but it's a bit old. During the tutorial, he uses this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    // Action
})
```

The problem is that - I think - this type of code was deprecated with Swift 4: what do I have to do to "translate" it and use it in my app?

Answer (score 1):

**swift 4.2 / Xcode 10.1**

if you need to run your code block in the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      //your code block
}
```